# Como calcular duas colunas e comparar o resultado com outra coluna?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tenho uma tabela, onde estou trazendo dois resultados diferentes com a query abaixo:

```
select sum(qtde_pontos) from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto where re = '9289'
    and natureza_operacao = '2' 
    and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
    and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10'
    union
select sum(qtde_pontos) from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto where re = '9289'
    and natureza_operacao = '1' 
    and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
    and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10'
```

O output é o seguinte:

```
480.00
545.00
```

No caso, eu gostaria de subtrair o valor 545.00 menos o 480.00 e o resultado disso (65.00), comparar com uma outra tabela que eu tenho chamada: **cc_ponto_saldo_vecto** comparando com a coluna **ponto_saldo_atual**. E dessa forma me trazendo se o resultado (65.00) é ou não diferente da coluna "ponto_saldo_atual".

É possível fazer isso?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Se está usando somente SQLServer ou tem uma linguagem no meio disso tudo, ou você quer criar um StoredProcedure e fazer isso, as opções são várias, como se vai comparar com a outra tabela?

Comment: A principio eu gostaria apenas de fazer isso em SQL pra ver o resultado. Posteriormente, eu levaria para PHP. Mas primeiro queria saber se é possível no SQL.

Sobre a comparação, minha dúvida são duas: trazer o resultado dos dois select e comparar esse valor com outra tabela.

Comment: Com storedprocedure acredito que resolva

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acumular os resultados e mostrá-los da seguinte forma:

```
WITH calculo (montante) AS (
  SELECT (SELECT SUM(qtde_pontos)
            FROM dbo.tbl_cc_ponto
           WHERE re = '9289'
             AND natureza_operacao = '1' 
             AND data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
             AND data_lacto <= '2017-08-10') -
         (SELECT SUM(qtde_pontos)
            FROM dbo.tbl_cc_ponto
           WHERE re = '9289'
             AND natureza_operacao = '2' 
             AND data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
             AND data_lacto <= '2017-08-10') AS montante
)
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT c.montante
                 FROM calculo c) <> cpsv THEN 'DIFERENTE'
         ELSE 'IGUAL'
       END AS resultado,
       cpsv.*
  FROM cc_ponto_saldo_vecto cpsv
```

Comment: Acho que esse daria certo, mas ele está dando um erro: Invalid column name 'cpsv'.

Comment: Desculpa minha falha, não tinha entendido a query. Agora que eu parei para analisar bloco a bloco, entendi que estava falantaod colocar a coluna de comparação. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente esta query:

```
select 
sum(natureza_operacao = '1' ) as operacao1,
sum(natureza_operacao = '2' ) as operacao2,
(sum(natureza_operacao = '1' ) - sum(natureza_operacao = '2' )) as resultado
 from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto 
 where re = '9289'
    and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
    and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (
         SUM(CASE WHEN natureza_operacao = '1' THEN qtde_pontos ELSE 0 END)  
          -
         SUM(CASE WHEN natureza_operacao = '2' THEN qtde_pontos ELSE 0 END) 
       ) as resultado
    from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto 
    where re = '9289'
     and data_lacto between '2012-01-01' AND '2017-08-10'
    GROUP BY natureza_operacao
```

Acredito que isso funcionei, ou pode fazer só o ajuste no seu sql. 
Assim:

```
SELECT 
 (select sum(qtde_pontos) from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto where re = '9289'
  and natureza_operacao = '1' 
  and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01' and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10')
-
(select sum(qtde_pontos) from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto where re = '9289'
    and natureza_operacao = '2' 
    and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01' and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma **CASE** forçando um sinal , solução comum para casos como este onde há sinal em valores não sinalizados.
Não vejo necessidade de se complicar a *query*.

```
select sum((qtde_pontos) * (case when natureza_operacao = '1' then 1 else -1 end)) total_pontos
from dbo.tbl_cc_ponto 
where re = '9289'
    and natureza_operacao in ('1','2') 
    and data_lacto >= '2012-01-01'
    and data_lacto <= '2017-08-10'
```

[Case](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)